# React : How to safely display a component according to user role

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am trying to display an admin Dashboard in `react` and `Meteor` only if the current user is *an admin*.

I am calling a server method that checks the user permission and rendering the admin component only if this method returns `true`.

This server call is asynchronous and thus the component is not rendering, usually I manage this asynchronous call with state, but I don't want to expose anything in state here (wouldn't like someone to change the state and access the admin dashboard).

Here is the code:

```js
export default class AdminChecker extends Component {
  isItAdmin() {
    // Get the id of current user
    const userId = Meteor.userId();
    if (userId) {
      // call a server method which returns true if current user is Admin
      Meteor.call('checkAdminId', userId, (err, authorized) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return null;
        }
        return (authorized) ? <AdminDashboard /> : null;
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="admin-temp-container">
        {this.isItAdmin()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think I can have this logic in a parent component and send the result of `isItAdmin` to `adminDashboard` as a prop (the `adminDashboard` component would display information only if its props is `true`).

But I am insure if this is safe. Could one change the props with Chrome react developer tools or something like that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, a prop can be changed with little effort in the console. Your approach in not particulally safe but might be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: It is very hard to make client components depending on a Boolean flag that indicates an admin role. You need definitely for everything a method counterpart because you need to assume that someone's makes it to fake the admin role on the client side

Comment: I don't know if that will help you, but usually in my projects, I use the redux store to get the user's role and I write a higher order component that reads the state from the redux store and renders the right component and of course the redux devtools must be enabled only in development mode.

Comment: Forget to mention that very sensitive areas could also be rendered server side and data which is only for admins can be published only if roles match

Comment: I can't help but add, that you _shall not_ have any sensitive information on client. Do _not_ trust clients at all. In your particular case the only _safe_ solution would be an SSR. All other ones will be vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, so basically I should move all this logic on the server side and render it using something like reactdomserver, is that right ?

Comment: I do not agree with @Styx that SSR is necessary here.  I ran out of space in the comment box, so I have moved my response to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are two parts to this (and the comments are hinting at both):

First, you should not expect to be able to enforce security on the client.  You must implement access control logic on the server (i.e., any API that performs an admin action must check that the user performing the action is an admin).

Once you've done that (and perhaps you already have), then you likely need to use props or state to store whether or not the user is an admin (just like you would store any other data in your app).

The key point is that once you enforce security on the server, then it doesn't really matter if a user manipulates the state to get to the admin dashboard: the server will not let the user view any real data or take any actions anyway.

This is completely unrelated to server-side rendering.  You can most certainly build a secure admin dashboard without server-side rendering, as long as the APIs used to fetch the admin data and perform admin actions are implementing their own access control checks.

Comment: I completely agree with you on that, but the question itself was _not_ about implementing server-side checks or something like that. The question was "Is it a safe way to show/hide _UI component_ on _client_, based on user's role". To _that_ my answer is "It is _never_ safe to trust client". For this particular question _the only safe_ solution is an SSR.

Comment: I suppose I can see SSR being used as a workaround for access control when fetching the data to populate the admin dashboard.  But what about calling APIs to take actions?  I suppose you wouldn't be able to use AJAX... you would need to use HTML forms or something.

Comment: Even if you did all that to implement client-side access control, you still have the problem that you have a service that is allowing arbitrary users to perform admin actions.  Then you expose yourself to a wide array of vulnerabilities.  e.g., you would need to block internet access to the service (in case someone discovers the API).  But even then, any arbitrary code execution vulnerability anywhere in your environment would grant access to these admin functions.

Comment: (and the list of vulnerabilities goes on, but these comments are too short to list them all...)

Comment: Why do you think that SSR should be a _replacement_ for control checks in API? These two things are _not_ exclusive. API should control check, of course, but the question itself was not about that.

Comment: I just mentioned SSR in order to even hide inputs controls or any other element that may indicate potential attack vectors. Of course this is just an addition to a proper and secure api design. But you summarized it well.

Comment: Thank you, this is much clearer, Indeed all my api actions are checking for user role in the first place so that should do it but since i'm not a security expert my plan is to hide information as much as possible so i am going to see if i can SSR the dashboard just to be extra-secure. (and that would be a great opportunity to learn more about SSR) 

Thank you all !